# What is the impact when Marketing Cloud Connector user's password changes?

Tags: salesforce, connector, exacttarget

We have set up Marketing Cloud Connector to integrate Marketing Cloud and Sales Cloud. We need to change password for our user that we created in Sales Cloud(having 'Admin' permissions). Will it have any repercussions on our Connector or our active journeys in SFMC?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you set up a marketing cloud connect user you would need to create the permission on the profile level so that the password never expires.

Moreover, If you are using connected app in salesforce, you would not need to associate password with connect user.

Hope this helps!!